# Update values in the dictionary with values from another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict_src =
{'TABLE1': [{'COLUMN1': '150', 'COLUMN2': 1500, 'COLUMN3': 1500, 'COLUNM4': None}, 
{'COLUMN1': '151', 'COLUMN2': 1520, 'COLUMN3': 1520, 'COLUNM4': None}, 
{'COLUMN1': '152', 'COLUMN2': 1520, 'COLUMN3': 1530, 'COLUNM4': None}]}

dict_changes = 
{'values_changed': {"root['TABLE1'][1]['COLUMN1']": {'new_value': '154', 'old_value': '152'}, 
"root['TABLE1'][0]['COLUMN1']": {'new_value': '152', 'old_value': '151'}, 
"root['TABLE1'][0]['COLUMN2']": {'new_value':1520, 'old_value': 1510}, 
"root['TABLE1'][0]['COLUMN3']": {'new_value': 1530, 'old_value': 1510}}}
```

I need to replace the column values in dict_src to new_value from dict_changes in corresponding records (3 columns in the first record and 1 in the second) and return new dictionary.

old_value doesn't matter.

The expected results is the following:

```
dict_final =
{'TABLE1': [{'COLUMN1': '152', 'COLUMN2': 1520, 'COLUMN3': 1530, 'COLUNM4': None}, 
{'COLUMN1': '154', 'COLUMN2': 1520, 'COLUMN3': 1520, 'COLUNM4': None}]}
```

What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: Why was the 3rd item in the list removed in `dict_final`? Or do you mean to remove items which are not updated?

Comment: It is important for the community that you _also_ demonstrate you are working to solve this problem. The best way to do that is to include the **text** of the source code you have so far (even if it is not working quite right). Do you have any control on the format of the changes dict? for example, it would be easier if one could work with a list of keys for example.

Comment: yes, items which are not updated should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Iterate over each `values_changed` e.g. `"root['TABLE1'][1]['COLUMN1']": {'new_value': '154', 'old_value': '152'},`
2. Get all the nested keys e.g. `['TABLE1', 1, 'COLUMN1']`
3. Traverse the source dictionary using the nested keys in step-2 to go to the target inner field e.g. `dict_src['TABLE1'][1]['COLUMN1']`
4. Update the inner target field e.g. `dict_src['TABLE1'][1]['COLUMN1'] = dict_changes['values_changed']["root['TABLE1'][1]['COLUMN1']"]['new_value']`
5. Mark the item as updated e.g. `dict_src['TABLE1'][1]['__updated__'] = True`
6. Once done, iterate over the items of the source dictionary
7. Filter out the items that were not updated

```
import re

dict_src = {
    'TABLE1': [
        {'COLUMN1': '150', 'COLUMN2': 1500, 'COLUMN3': 1500, 'COLUNM4': None}, 
        {'COLUMN1': '151', 'COLUMN2': 1520, 'COLUMN3': 1520, 'COLUNM4': None}, 
        {'COLUMN1': '152', 'COLUMN2': 1520, 'COLUMN3': 1530, 'COLUNM4': None}
    ]
}

dict_changes = {
    'values_changed': {
        "root['TABLE1'][1]['COLUMN1']": {'new_value': '154', 'old_value': '152'}, 
        "root['TABLE1'][0]['COLUMN1']": {'new_value': '152', 'old_value': '151'}, 
        "root['TABLE1'][0]['COLUMN2']": {'new_value':1520, 'old_value': 1510}, 
        "root['TABLE1'][0]['COLUMN3']": {'new_value': 1530, 'old_value': 1510}
    }
}

# Update the original dict
key_re = re.compile(r"\['?(\w+)'?\]")
for key, value in dict_changes["values_changed"].items():
    # Find the nested keys to the target field
    nested_keys = key_re.findall(key)
    # Go inner to the nested keys of the original dict
    obj = dict_src
    for nested in nested_keys[:-1]:
        if nested.isdigit():
            nested = int(nested)
        obj = obj[nested]
    # Update the inner target field which we accessed step by step via the nested keys
    obj[nested_keys[-1]] = value["new_value"]  # This will update the original dict. If that shouldn't be done, use copy.deepcopy() first.
    # Set a flag to notify that this was updated
    obj['__updated__'] = True

# Filter only the items that are updated
dict_final = {
    key: list(
        map(
            lambda columns: {key: value for key, value in columns.items() if key != '__updated__'},  # Remove the flag '__updated__' which we only added to mark the items that were updated
            filter(lambda columns: '__updated__' in columns, value)  # Filter only the items that were updated
        )
    )
    for key, value in dict_src.items()
}

print(dict_final)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "TABLE1": [
        {"COLUMN1": "152", "COLUMN2": 1520, "COLUMN3": 1530, "COLUNM4": null},
        {"COLUMN1": "154", "COLUMN2": 1520, "COLUMN3": 1520, "COLUNM4": null}
    ]
}
```